# Understanding Proof of Projection Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The theorem states that $M$ is a closed convex subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Then there exist unique pair of mapping $P:H\to M$ and $Q:H \to M^\perp$ such that $Px+Qx=x \forall x,\in H$.

Define $P:H\to M$ to be the closest point to $x$ in $M$. And $Qx=x-Px$. Which gives us what we want for $P$. Now to show $Q$ as it is in the theorem, we consider $m\in M^\perp$ be the unit vector. Let $Px+\alpha m\in M$ given some complex number $\alpha$. Then by the definition of $P$ we must have the following $$\|x-Px+\alpha m\|\geq \|Px-x\|$$
then proof involves the following inequality which I can not reproduce. Set $z=x-Px$ and we have $$\|z\|^2+|\alpha|^2\|m\|^2- \langle \alpha m,z\rangle-\langle z,\alpha m \rangle \geq \|z\|^2$$
I am thinking its triangle inequality but then I can only deduce the following
$$\|z\|^2+|\alpha|^2\|m\|^2 +2 |\alpha|\|z\| \|m\|\geq \|z\|^2$$
Also and then the proof deduced that $\langle z,m \rangle=0$ from above but I dont see how this is true as well.

Im guessing Im not seeing some silly algebra here. But can someone explain the inequality? Thanks! Ive been looking at this for hours xd

Comment: Raise the first inequality to the second power.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Right but then I will get $\|\alpha z\|\|m\|$ instead of the two negative inner product

Comment: $$\|u+v\|^2=\|u\|^2+\|v\|^2+\langle u,v\rangle+ \langle v,u\rangle$$ $$= \|u\|^2+\|v\|^2 +2{\rm Re}\, \langle u,v\rangle $$